# How to find correlation between 2 variables but cross different timeline ('lagged correlation')

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, lag

Suppose that I'm selling stuffs that are complementary goods with each other.
And I'm trying to figure out correlation between item sales, but on different date of sales.

(Cuz I think sales of `item01` on d-day may affect sales of `item02~99` on `d+30`)

`dataframe` looks like this.

```
.    Item01  Item02  Item03 Item04  ... 

day1   120     130     140    200    ...

day2   200     200     150    119    ...

day3   162     110     180    220    ...

day4   170     130     160    190    ...

...    ...     ...     ...    ...    ...
```

I learned ways to use pandas dataframe's `.corr()`
but I want to find cross-time correlation.

should I just make my own regression function?

Thank you very much

```
df_sales = pd.DataFrame(dic_sales)

corr = df_sales.corr(method = 'pearson')
```

`corr val`

```
.            item01 Item02 ...

item01(d+30)  0.75   0.46  ...

item02(d+30)  0.44   0.84  ...

...           ...    ...
```

Comment: This is called ***lagged correlation***

Comment: e.g. ***correlation lagged by n days***

Comment: Apparently, you are looking for the autocorrelation of a time series https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.autocorr.html

Comment: @rafaelc: then ***lagged autocorrelation***, e.g. "Find the lag with peak autocorrelation"

Comment: @smci *lagged autocorrelation* is redundant. Autocorrelation implies a lag already

Comment: @rafaelc: ok, but lagged correlation (of series X with Y, lagged by n days) isn't

Answer (score 0):

Create new columns that are time-shifted by the 30 day lag period and then run the corr method against those columns.

```
df_shifted = df_sales.shift(periods=30)
df_shifted.columns = ['Item01_30','Item02_30','Item03_30','Item04_30']
```

will shift all records up 30 rows and leave NaN values in observations 0-29. Then add 30 NaN values to the end of the original dataframe:

```
empty_row = pd.Series([Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan], index=['Item01','Item02','Item03','Item04'])
for i in range(30):
    df_sales = df_sales.append(empty_row)
```

Next, combine df_shifted and df_sales into one dataframe:

```
frames = [df_sales, df_shifted]
df_sales_with_shift = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

Run the corr method only on the rows that don't have NaN values:

```
df_sales_with_shift[30:len(df_sales_with_shift.index)-30].corr(method ='pearson')
```

This will require you to reduce your dataset by the number of time periods you choose to shift, so depending on your sample size you may need to take care that you don't choose a time period too long.

Comment: Thank you a lot! it works! appreciate your answer. i just changed 'pd.concat(frames, axis=1)'